# Try Catch exception in a locked block of code

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, locking

I have an issue when there is an exception in a block of code that uses a lock.  I am reading and writing to a serial port and there are several different threads that need access to the same serial port.  This is managed by a lock.  I have no issues except if the serial port stops working.  This can happen since the software controls an RF transmitter and occasionally the rf can cause usb to serial ports to stop functioning.  If you then attempt to write to the port you will get a write timeout.  I tried handling this from a try - catch exception handler.  However, the program locks hard at that point and has to have the task killed.  I am not sure if this is coming from the exception or the message box I am trying to display since it could result from a background thread.  Here is the code:

```
        lock (_object)
        {
            try
            {
                if (portOpened)
                {
                    port.Write(data);
                }

                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The radio is not connected. Please select a ComPort in the settings dialog");

                }
            }

            catch (Exception x) //this will capture a write exception.
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The program is unable to write to the serial port. Select OK to close the program";

                Application.Exit();

            }

            finally
            {
            }

        }
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Why are you handing the exception *inside* the `lock` instead of *outside* of the `lock`?  And why are you interacting with the user from a non-UI thread, or even non-UI code, for that matter?  Separate the business logic from the user interface.

Comment: Locks should surround ONLY the code that needs to be protected against reentrancy.  In your case, looks like port.Write is all that needs locking.

Comment: @Will The `if` may need to be inside the `lock` too, assuming `portOpened` is shared with another thread.

Comment: @servy So you are saying put the try outside the lock and then the catch can deal with the exceptions.  Then I should use an invoke since this thread could be accessed by other background workers or the user interface.

Comment: What's the point of an empty `finally` clause? More important though, what is your actual question? You got one answer that does (I think) address the "locks hard" issue. But is that really all you need help with? Or is there more to this question than that? Your question doesn't mention `Invoke()` or `BackgroundWorker`, but your previous comment implies you need some help with those here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to force to exit the app, `Application.Exit` is not a good candidate, as it simply pushes the Close request on message queues of all threads, but does not force anything. If you want to stop app at any cost, use [Environment.Exit(exitCode)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit(v=vs.110).aspx), or may be even better [Environment.FailFast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd289240(v=vs.110).aspx), with specified exception so it will be logged into the system's log: convenient for future investigations.